# How to store Advance Python Scheduler Job on my database

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery-beat

I am trying to create various scheduling tasks to manage objects and store these jobs as a Django model on postgres and manage them through admin panel.

Could anybody please help me.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATED with **django-celery-beat**

- [pip](https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-beat/)
- [docs](https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [source](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat)

> pip install celery==4.4.6
> pip uninstall django-celery
> Now i have this project...

project/celery.py:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

app = Celery('celery_project')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

project/setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  ...
  'django_celery_beat',
  ...
]

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
  'scheduled_datetime_minute': {
    'task': 'scheduled_datetime',
    'schedule': 60.0,
  },
}
```

app/tasks.py

```
@shared_task(name='print_datetime')
def scheduled_datetime():
  from datetime import datetime
  print(datetime.now())
```

I have running the Redis server and running the Django project without errors, but nothing happens....

Comment: @ Alberto Sanmartin Martinez  take a look at https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html. I think this is what you want

Comment: @iliya i have updated the post with your help but does not work.